# Post is not working in the node js express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql, mean

When I try to pass the post request in the application, it is not working. When I try to post data using postman, data is not passing, and I get the following values as output.

> "_id": "615f2fe2fc52303bdb758e93", "saltSecret":
> "$2a$10$AmJCbqiunWY2S8kVBbx.a.", "__v": 0

These are my codes.

**app.js**

```
require("./config/config");
require("./models/db");

const express = require("express");
const bodyParse = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const rtsIndex = require("./route/index.router");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParse.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/api", rtsIndex);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Server started at port : ${process.env.PORT}`)
);
```

**studentModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

var studentScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    saltSecret: String,
});

studentScheme.pre("save", function (next) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            this.password = hash;
            this.saltSecret = salt;
            next();
        });
    });
});

mongoose.model("Student", studentScheme);
```

**studentController.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");    
const Student = mongoose.model("Student");

module.exports.resgiter = (req, res, next) => {
    var student = new Student();
    student.fullname = req.body.fullname;
    student.email = req.body.email;
    student.password = req.body.password;
    student.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err) res.send(doc);
    });
};
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();    
const ctrlStudent = require("../controller/student.controller");

router.post("/register", ctrlStudent.resgiter);

module.exports = router;
```

Please somebody help me; I don't understand what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it is always preferred to use `async - await` whenever it's like there is a promise (not the exact promise in nodejs , just a term I used here ) as such which it returns.

So by using `async - await` , I do not know how you data is stored in your database; but you can try out the code below and check whther that works or not:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Student = mongoose.model("Student");

module.exports.resgiter = async (req, res, next) => {
    var student = new Student({
        fullname: req.body.fullname,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    await student.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Saving the document...")
            res.send(doc);
        }
    });
};
```

You can refer to the links below for **async - await**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9

https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot

Comment: if that has worked, you can give a vote to the answer as well.....thank you